How to put value from coulmns to data value [Python]
I have data like this and first line appear to be columns (asd@gmail.com | 23 )



asd@gmail.com
23




zxc@gmail.com
22



I want it to be like this as gmail and age as columns and put the values in columns into data values



gmail
age




asd@gmail.com
23


zxc@gmail.com
22



programming lang: Python

Make sure to read your table passing the column names as parameter
